# How many special kind of numbers are there which are less than $M$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Natural numbers $n$ such that $N = p\times n^3 + h$ ends in $n$ for a prime $p$ and $0 ≤ h < p$ are called h-trimorphic ($5$ is $0$-trimorphic for all odd $p$). How many $7$-trimorphic less than $1000$ numbers are there?

Comment: @jxh $3 \times 5^3 = 375 + 0$ and ends in a $5$.

Comment: @UmbertoP.:  I clearly did not read the problem correctly, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "How many numbers less than $1000$ are there such that each is $7$-trimorphic _for all_ primes $p$" or "_for some_ prime $p$"?

Comment: Hi, user "near pi"; yes. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yes Umberto P, and 5 is obviously a "0-polymorphic number" also (the positive exponent arbitrary natural).

Comment: Hi 31415; my "yes" goes for "some prime p".

Comment: So if I wanted to demonstrate that $13$ is $7-$trimorphic I would have to find a prime $p \gt 7$ such that $p\cdot 13^3$ ends in $06$, right?

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-The question excludes the primes 2, 3, 5, 7 then p > 10 and one have to solve [image]
with M arbitrary

Comment: The expression to be solved is pn^3 = 10M )I don´t know if my Figure has appears

Comment: I have posted before as an image without problems some other mathematical expressions.

Comment: That works now (still as an image). Tanks you very much Ross.

Comment: This does not seem to correspond to the problem statement.  If you solve this, you will have $pn^3+h$ ending in $h$, not $n$  Solving this is easy-as we have excluded $p=5$ we must have $n$ a multiple of $10$ and we are done.

Comment: It is obvious I have to take a rest: I have “surmenage”. After a problem I want to post I will take a break for a while.Thanks Ross.